# Width of Table cell based on colgroup not working on both tables

Tags: html

I have 2 tables. The colgroup settings (percents) work in the first table but not the second one. I can't tell why the difference. Can anyone see why this is not working? I have compared these many  times and must be overlooking something. I can't post without adding some more comments but this is just a simple question. I will keep adding until it let's me post or not.

```html
<p>This example shows a colgroup that has three columns of different widths:</p>

<table id="table1" border="1" style="width: 100%">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
  </colgroup>

  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">
      <hr style="color:#000" />
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>col 1</td>
    <td>col 2</td>
    <td>col 3</td>
    <td>col 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table id="footer" border="1" style="width: 100%">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
  </colgroup>

  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">
      <hr style="color:#000" />
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      first row, first cell
    </td>

    <td>
      first row, second cell and qR
    </td>

    <td>
      first row, third cell
    </td>

    <td>
      first row, fourth cell
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      second row
    </td>

    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="100%">
      footer text actually "prints" at bottom
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the `width="100%"` in the first cell of your last row (which is unrealistic/impossible BTW: How could this cell be 100% wide if there are three more cells in that row?). Anyway, just remove `width="100%"` from that `td`and you are set.

```html
<p>This example shows a colgroup that has three columns of different widths:</p>

<table id="table1" border="1" style="width: 100%">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
  </colgroup>

  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">
      <hr style="color:#000" />
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>col 1</td>
    <td>col 2</td>
    <td>col 3</td>
    <td>col 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table id="footer" border="1" style="width: 100%">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
    <col style="width: 25%"></col>
  </colgroup>

  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">
      <hr style="color:#000" />
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      first row, first cell
    </td>

    <td>
      first row, second cell and qR
    </td>

    <td>
      first row, third cell
    </td>

    <td>
      first row, fourth cell
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      second row
    </td>

    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      footer text actually "prints" at bottom
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove 3 unnecessary cells from footer table last row, and change `width="100%"` to `colspan="4"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML colgroup Tag</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This example shows a colgroup that has three columns of different widths:</p>

        <table id="table1" border = "1" style="width: 100%">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 25%"></col>
                <col style="width: 25%"></col>
                <col style="width: 25%"></col>
                <col style="width: 25%"></col>
            </colgroup>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="4"><hr style="color:#000"/></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>col 1</td>
                <td>col 2</td>
                <td>col 3</td>
                <td>col 4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <br><br><br>


        <table id="footer" border="1" style="width: 100%">
            <colgroup>
               <col style="width: 25%"></col>
               <col style="width: 25%"></col>
               <col style="width: 25%"></col>
               <col style="width: 25%"></col>
            </colgroup>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="4"><hr style="color:#000"/></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    first row, first cell
                </td>

                <td>
                    first row, second cell and qR
                </td>

                <td>
                    first row, third cell
                </td>

                <td>
                    first row, fourth cell
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    second row
                </td>

                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    footer text actually "prints" at bottom
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```